# Firebase Hosting - Compute Engine Server HTTPS & Certificates

Tags: firebase, https, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

I have:

- a website hosted on Firebase, implemented around the ReactJS Framework
- a server with a REST API deployed on Google Compute Engine

Because Firebase Hosting is served through https it is required that Compute Engine also serves the API through https. Of course if the certificate is self-signed, I would get a silent error in the browser that the connection to the external server is not allowed (certificate warning). I could manually go that url and accept the certificate but that is not an option for production.

It seems like my options are limited to buying a domain, buy a ssl certificate, create a load balancer resource in Google Cloud to which I assign the domain and the certificate. I could install the certificate directly to the server, but I would rather have the load balancer in front and switch to http.

The problem is buying a certificate instead of using the https certificate in Firebase. Do I have other options for making this connection work?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you already listed all the options available. Did you end up buying a certificate?

Comment: Could you make this work? Facing the exact same issue. Thanks.